# Reading data from firebase database with delay

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase database. Now in my onCreate method I am trying to read some data using ValueEventListener(). I read that data and store locally in a hashmap. Now after that I am using loader and an adapter.

In the adapter using I want to use the data that I read earlier from the database.
But the hashmap is always empty when adapter is called.

When I view the logs in android studio the event listener is eventually called but after the adapter is executed.

So does the event listener always run in the background thread and that's the reason its triggered with a delay? If yes, then how can I make sure that the adapter is called only after the data is read from the firbase database.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Sourabhlpu/e92d5d21fc6338bf8ccbc2fd44b47182) is he link to my code.

Comment: Instead of describing the code, edit your question to include the actual code that your asking about. Such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way to maximize your chances of getting help on code-related questions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your suggestion. Here is the link to my code. [link](https://gist.github.com/Sourabhlpu/e92d5d21fc6338bf8ccbc2fd44b47182)

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen said *include the actual code that your asking about*. Do not use links or images as links break which invalidates the question and embedded images make us have to retype existing code in the answer which makes us grumpy. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there but there is one more thing that you need to do. You need to move the declaration of your `HashMap` inside `onDataChange()` method otherwise it will always be empty. This is happening because of the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method which is called before you are tryind to add those values to the map. So your code should look like this:

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, String> mBookmarkIds = new HashMap<>();
        for(DataSnapshot bookmarkIdSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            mBookmarkIds.put(bookmarkIdSnapshot.getValue().toString(), bookmarkIdSnapshot.getKey());
        }
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "the bookmark ids are " + mBookmarkIds);
        NewsPreferences.setmBookmarkIds(mBookmarkIds);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
```

Comment: Actually it did initialize the hashmap which doesn't cause the app to crash. But the hashmap is still empty when the loader is started.

Comment: Add also the database structure.

Comment: Not sure why you want to see the database structure. The data is finally loaded but that is done after the loader has already started. 
In short, I want to pause the onCreate() method until onDataChange is completed. Still if you need the database structure I can add it.

Comment: You cannot pause the `onCreate()` method. Maybe it's connectivity problem. Have you tried on another device with different internet connectivity?

Comment: Yes you are right I think its not right to pause the onCreate() as well. Can I post a link to my project on github here?

Comment: Yes you can post it.

Comment: [github link](https://github.com/Sourabhlpu/NewsFeedV1/blob/firebase/app/src/main/java/com/example/personal/newsfeeder/MainActivityFragment.java) 
Here is the link to the fragment that contains the above listener code in the onCreateView() (line number 172) in my project on github.